# Best way to move functions from postgresql to another

Tags: postgresql

I'm not familiar with postgres but I'm sure there has to be a way to source control its functions.
Currently my team adds functions on a postgresql database directly, and when it's time to deploy to production they just move the functions manually, so it's natural to forget to move certain functions.

Is there a tool similar to git that would allow them to branch out, merge and deploy?

Comment: Have a look at tools like Liquibase or Flyway. There are other tools listed on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schema_migration Of course you need to put _those_ scripts into Git or Subversion

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom PostgreSQL extension created with [`CREATE EXTENSION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createextension.html).

Put all of your extension code in a build system and have your developers work on that. Then you can install the extensions easily and version control them, roll them back, upgrade them, etc.

Here is a [tutorial to get started.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/extend-extensions.html)

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach, using the PostgreSQL tools and `git` (or the CVS of your choice), is to have a periodic task (with `cron` or equivalent) that runs a script doing two things:

1. `pg_dump` the schema of your development database into a `schema.sql` file, by means of: `pg_dump --host my_host --username "postgres" --format plain --schema-only --create --encoding --file schema.sql my_database`  (you should have .pgpass adequally set to deal with identification/authorization).
2. `git add schema.sql | git commit -a -m "Possible schema changes to the DB"`

Even if this is not perfect, it allows to have a (daily?) record of schema changes. When you need to deploy all those changes, your `schema.sql` has all the SQL instructions necessary.

It is not easy to have branches and merges, but it would be actually possible if, as part of your "switch branch process", you actually drop your database and recreate it from `schema.sql`, and have some extra mechanism to fill it with adequate data. `git` can deal with `schema.sql` because it's a text file, it could also deal with a `database.sql` that would include all the data (assuming the size is reasonable).

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own template Database and store just the custom functions there.

When deploying you can just backup and restore this database as SQL.

Link to [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/manage-ag-templatedbs.html)